# Can a sequence of functions with bounded derivative converge to something unbounded?

Tags: limits, functions

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $h_n$ on the interval $[0,1]$ with uniformly bounded Lipschitz norm, $\sup_{x,y } \frac{|h_n(x)-h_n(y)|}{|x-y|}$. Let $h_n$ converge to some function $h$ in a *continuous* norm.

Is it true that the Lipschitz norm of $h$ is bounded as well ?

I would like it to be true but I have a feeling of counterexample although I am not able to find it. Any sequence of functions that I construct with a bounded derivative gives me a bounded derivative for the limit.

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by a continuous norm?

Comment: +1 for "I would like it to be true but I have a feeling of counterexample" because that is such a recognizable state of being when dealing with this sort of problem. A question though: what do you mean by 'converge in a continuous norm'?

Comment: Yes: it is true.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be the uniform Lipschitz bound. Then $|h_n(x) - h_n(y)| \le M |x-y|$ for all $n$ and for all $x,y \in [0,1]$. All you require for the limit $h$ to be Lipschitz with the same constant is pointwise convergence: $h_n(t) \to h(t)$ for all $t$.

Comment: You are so right and gosh was it so simple :|I am ashamed I didn't see it myself.